# Read from Python NamedTemporaryFile After Write From Outside Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, subprocess, temporary-files

If I write to a Python NamedTemporaryFile under specific conditions, the data written to the file cannot be read using the `.seek(0)` and then `.read()` methods. Is there a way to get this to work as expected?

Here is a case where data is written to the temp file using `vi`:

```py
import subprocess
import tempfile

tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
# Stop here and open file in vi on command line, write "test", and save.
tf.seek(0)
print(tf.read())
```

Here the output is empty, but the file does contain the data if you use `cat` from the command line on the file.

```
b''
```

Here is a case where data is written using the macOS screenshot command:

```py
import subprocess
import tempfile

tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
command = f'screencapture {tf.name}'
p = subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
tf.seek(0)
print(tf.read())
```

Again, here the output is empty, but the file is actually populated with PNG data. This can be tested by using `head -c 4` command on the file.

```
b''
```

Here is one case where everything works as expected:

```py
import subprocess
import tempfile

tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
command = f'echo test > {tf.name}'
p = subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
tf.seek(0)
print(tf.read())
```

Output:

```
b'test\n'
```

The following code works, but does not use the temp file's handle to read. I am looking for an answer that uses the temp file's handle to seek and read etc.

```py
import pathlib
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tf:
    subprocess.run(['screencapture', tf.name])
    data = pathlib.Path(tf.name).read_bytes()
```

Comment: Just a guess: `vi` and `screencapture` may unlink the open file, meaning they detach it from the file name entry in the directory and link the name to a newly created file. If the unlinked file wouldn't be open it would be deleted instantly.